# How to run a script from crontab and avoid "LoadError"

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, cron, rvm

I want run my script from the crontab on Mac OS, but I'm getting an error:

```
ruby: Operation not permitted -- /Users/vitalii/Desktop/Home/update/update.rb (LoadError)
```

My preferences for the cron task and settings are created using `rvm cron setup`:

```
#sm start rvm
PATH="/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME='/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1'
GEM_PATH='/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1:/Users/vitalii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global'
MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/vitalii/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1'
IRBRC='/Users/vitalii/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/.irbrc'
RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.4.1'
#sm end rvm

* * * * * ruby /Users/vitalii/Desktop/Home/update/update.rb >> /Users/vitalii/Desktop/logfile.txt 2>&1
```

I gave each file the rights to execute with `chmod 777`, but there are no changes and the error is repeated.

The contents of the file `update.rb` are

```
puts 'Hello, World!!!'
```

Can someone tell me what's going on and what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I haven't used `rvm cron setup` before, is it the same crontab that's opened with `crontab -e`? If so you could try by commenting  the environmental variables and using full ruby path `/bin/ruby` or `/home/<user>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x.x.x/bin/ruby`

Comment: "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)" are useful.

Comment: Does `/Users/vitalii/Desktop/Home/update` actually exist? `Home` is suspicious as typically we wouldn't have a directory named that, but we _do_ have an environment variable called `$HOME` which is equivalent to `~` and `/Users/vitalii`. Notice that it's different than where you're redirecting output to: `/Users/vitalii/Desktop/logfile.txt`

Comment: @theTinMan, Home it’s my home directory project and yes, I’m used her for my project. Logfile.txt will be different because it is located in a different location.

Comment: @Vitalii : The error mesage means that Ruby encountered an [EPERM](https://lwn.net/Articles/532771/) error when loading the file. Does it work if you run the same command from your command line? Would `ruby -e 'puts "hello"' >> ...` in your crontab work?

Comment: @user1934428 I found solution, since I use mojave, I need to make additional settings in the system. Who would have thought ...

https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, since I use Mojave.
I need to make additional settings in the system. Who would have thought ... 
[enter link description here](https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/)

This turns out to be a problem, since you need to allow permissions for cron.
And correct run command for crontab -e, this
`* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /Users/vitalii/Desktop/Home/update/update.rb'`

Answer (score 0):

There is a little difference when setting crontab job via `crontab -e` or putting them in `/etc/crontab`

```
$ crontab -e
# m h dom mon dow command
  * *   *  *  *   echo ok

$ nano /etc/crontab
# m h dom mon dow user command
  * *   *  *  *   root echo ok
```

Is this the case?

Comment: Not exactly. The problem was in mojave itself, you need to install a couple of settings in the system